# How to apply css pointer grab on div?

Tags: css, cursor

I have a div, and this css

```
        #sliderContainer {
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        #sliderContainer:active {
            cursor:move;
        }
```

I want it so that the default cursor on it is pointer, but then when I click with left click and keep it held down as I pan the mouse, the cursor should be grab/move. However this doesn't work.

Anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to work for me, over at JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LdjagLsu/ (with aesthetic additions in order to cover the view-port and have visible dimensions and colour).

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```js
$("#sliderContainer").mousedown(function(){
 $(this).css("cursor","move");
});

$("#sliderContainer").mouseup(function(){
 $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
});
```

```css
#sliderContainer {
            cursor:pointer;
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sliderContainer">Example</div>
```

> WATCHOUT

You only need this css:

```
#sliderContainer {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

and this javascript (if you don't want to use jquery you can convert it):

```
$("#sliderContainer").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css("cursor","move");
});

$("#sliderContainer").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
});
```